# Which Books Comprised The Houghton Mifflin Modern Mathematics Series

Tags: textbooks

Around the 1960s a collection of math books by authors such as Mary P. Dolciani, William Wooton, Edwin F. Beckenbach, Ray C. Jurgensen etc. started to appear which were part of a series of books called "Modern Mathematics Series" by the company Houghton Mifflin.

What I want to know is:

1. What are the books that make up this series? There are several books, each with multiple editions and revisions. They have similar names, but some have the prefix "Modern" and some don't. Some have the subtitle "Structure and method", and some don't.
2. What are the levels that each book is intended to (middle school, high school, first year of college, etc.)?

Comment: Can you tell us what google gave you and something about where you got stuck?

Comment: In the olden days, before the internet, there were these wonderfully trained people called librarians, who could track down almost any book. At my institution, they still exist, and they love it when people take advantage of their peculiar skill set. If you have access to a library, you might ask there. Even a public library might have someone with some training in research, at least at a main branch. Someone has to curate the book collection. -- Alternatively, this HMH page has an email for questions about their history: https://www.hmhco.com/about-us/our-legacy

Comment: Are you looking for all the titles including the "Readiness book to accompany [other title]" and "Diagnostic tests to accompany [other title]" and "Workbook to accompany [other title]" and "Solution key for [other title]"? Or just the list of main "[other title]"?

Comment: @shoover, just the list of main "[other title]".

Answer (score 1):

They were high school textbooks (maybe used in middle school if people took algebra in middle school).  My father, who taught high school math for many years, has some. Just searching on the series name and author names you can easily locate some online about [trigonometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000J4N96Y), [pre-algebra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0395143853), [algebra 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001JYSMKG), [algebra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0007GU5S4),
[geometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0007E5VHQ).